# Locked Staking - when can I cash out?

Tags: staking

I'm trying to understand how locked staking works.

Per my understanding, there's a staking period during which it is impossible to withdraw the staked coins.

My question is: what happens after this staking period? Can I safely withdraw my coins and my interest?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read in details but yes you will be able to withdraw your locked fund. I don't know if you can only withdraw interest and let your full stack.

However, remember that a limited number of stack are created every day. So stacker have to wait to get valid. You can exit easily but entering take days or weeks.